# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje de error al rebasar el MaxLength solamente en la fila donde se esta editando un campo dentro de un mat table?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Tengo la siguiente tabla en donde el campo  **Comentario** es editable y la validación que agrego es que solo permita 15 caracteres, si el  usuario rebasa el limite quiero que se pinte un mensaje de error, y ya lo hace, pero el mensaje lo muestra en todos los campos de la tabla y yo solo quiero que se muestre en el campo que estoy editando, no en todos.

asi se muestra el mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollme">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="select-css" [ngClass]="{'text-red': element.cveEstado=='ERR',
        'text-green': element.cveEstado=='INP', 'text-orange': element.cveEstado=='PEN'}">
          <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
            [disabled]="!element.editar">

            <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado"
            [disabled]="deshabilitarOpcion(element.cveEstado).includes(estatus.descripcion)">
              {{ estatus.descripcion }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <br>
          <span class="error" *ngIf="limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo es de 15 caracteres</span>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar"  />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
              (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'botonSave',
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  horaIngresada: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];
  horaInvalida = true;
  limiteExcedido = false;
  
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
    
  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
    if (this.comentIngresado.length > 15) {
      this.limiteExcedido = true;
      e.target.value = this.comentIngresado.slice(0, 15);
    } else {
      this.limiteExcedido = false;
    }
  }

 //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
 changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
  this.horaIngresada = e.value;
  console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
  this.validarHora();
}

validarHora() {
  console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
  const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
  this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
  console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
}


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
  }

  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }

  deshabilitarOpcion(cveEstado: string): string[] {
    console.log("disabled    ",cveEstado);
    switch (cveEstado) {
      case 'INP':
        return ['FINISHED','PENDING'];
      case 'En Proceso':
        return ['Iniciado'];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }

  guardar(element: any) {
    if (element.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = false;

      if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
        alert('No se han modificado campos');
      } else {
        console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
        this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
        this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
          this.fechaIngresada
        );

        console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
        this.controlService
          .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.controlModel = data;
            this.comentIngresado = '';
            this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
            this.fechaIngresada = '';

            alert('Agregado correctamente');
          });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = true;
    }
  }
}
```

es en el metodo changeValue() donde agregué la validación, como puedo hacerle para que solo se pinte en el campo que estoy editando y no en todos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la función ChangeValue ya tienes acceso al objeto de la fila que se esta modificando por lo tanto podrías agregarle la propiedad limiteExcedido, de tal forma que cada fila tendrá su propia propiedad y así evitar mostrar el mensaje de error para todos los demás.

La función quedaría así:

```
changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
    if (this.comentIngresado.length > 15) {
      row.limiteExcedido = true;
      e.target.value = this.comentIngresado.slice(0, 15);
    } else {
      row.limiteExcedido = false;
    }
  }
```

En el archivo HTML puedes usar la propiedad así:

```
 <span class="error" *ngIf="element.limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo es de 15 caracteres</span>
```

Al obtener la data mostrada en la tabla podrías inicializar dicha propiedad en false:

```
 private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      this.control = this.control.map( item => ({ ...item, limiteExcedido: false }) )
      console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias :), me funcionó